# Start temporary mysql container when running tests in Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, docker

I am looking for a way to start a mysql container to be used only for my tests when run from Intellij. I have already configured docker-maven plugin for spring boot that will start the container when I run

> mvn install

and close it down after tests are executed. However if I try to run a test directly from IntelliJ, that container won't be started. Is there a way to configure this behavior, perhaps using test profile ?

Comment: You may want to have a look at testcontainers https://www.testcontainers.org/

Answer (score 0):

Create a new application properties file:
'application-test.properties'

Use the @TestPropertySource in tests to set the property source [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html)

Comment: Also, by doing this, you can use an in memory (H2) source or better yet...a separate database schema which will mirror more exactly how your code will behave.